# Django querySet order by date closest to today

Tags: django

I have a simple view that returns event dates and then is presented within a table on my page.

I need to order the data by the date closest to the current date only for dates in the future, not for dates that have passed.

This is my view

```
def dashboard_view(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().date
    game_list=Game.objects.all()
    event_list = Event.objects.all().order_by('event_date')
    
    return render(request,"dashboard.html",{"game_list":game_list, "event_list": event_list})
```

I was thinking of using `datetime.datetime.now()` but I can't figure out the logic/syntax to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `Event`s with `Event.objects.filter(event_date__gte=today)` to retrieve only `Event`s that start today or in the future:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def dashboard_view(request):
    today = now().date()
    game_list=Game.objects.all()
    event_list = Event.objects.filter(event_date__gte=today).order_by('event_date')
    
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'game_list':game_list, 'event_list': event_list})
```

Comment: So easy :) Thank you